# Load voltage and current of relays

Tags: motor, switches, inverter

https://www.zoro.com/schneider-electric-iec-magnetic-contactor-24v-coil-9a-lc1d093bl/i/G0569497/

Hello guys, I'm very new to relays and practically know nothing about what to look for and how to select one. I'm trying to insert a three phase relay between the inverter output and the electric machine. The voltage during the "blocking mode" will have the inverter switching frequency component.

For a common relay like this, does it matter if the "conducting" voltage and current have a frequency of a few kHz?

In the relay product page I attached above, it only says the coil volt is 24 V. Do relays also have a "breakdown voltage" or "blocking voltage" like IGBT or MOSFET?

Also, what about solid state relays?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: can you turn the inverter off instead?

Comment: Get the data sheet from Schneider. The linked catalog page is not helpful. It is generally recommended not to insert a relay between the inverter output and the electric machine. Be sure to review the inverter (VFD) manufacturer recommendations about that.

Comment: @Jasen I'm trying to break the inverter-machine connection and connect the switching nodes to the grid. So just turning off the inverter is not valid since I need it operating.

Answer (score 0):

> ... The voltage during the "blocking mode" will have the inverter
>   switching frequency component.

Not a good idea as Charles Cowie said, you can damage the inverter output. But moving on to your questions...

> For a common relay like this, does it matter if the "conducting"
>   voltage and current have a frequency of a few kHz?

As a gross generalized rule, it is permissible (from the contactor's standpoint) for it to be used on the output side of an inverter, it is generally done on safety systems. But contactors used in machine safety systems have other requirements, such as "force guided contacts" that this particular contactor does not have. So be careful about what you are planning on here.

> In the relay product page I attached above, it only says the coil volt
>   is 24 V. Do relays also have a "breakdown voltage" or "blocking
>   voltage" like IGBT or MOSFET?

Not in the same way as electronic components. Relays have a "working voltage", in this case 600VAC maximum. There is also a dielectric breakdown voltage, usually much higher than the actual working voltage, but that does come into play when attempting to interrupt an arc coming from an inverter that is firing at a high carrier frequency. this contactor will be fine, but again, the INVERTER may not like having an arc opening on the output under load.

> Also, what about solid state relays?

Absolutely out of the question.

Describe what you are attempting to accomplish with this, there may be better ways to get there.